# UITableViewCell + Autolayout + RTL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, localization, autolayout

I'm localising my app to Hebrew, which is an RTL language.
Each cell has horizontal constraints set as Leading/Trailing which are automatically reversed on RTL languages.
The final result is exactly as expected, but when scrolling through the table view, the UITableViewCell subviews are **animating** from LTR to RTL, which is very weird.

Is there a work around for preventing the views from animating?

Example:

[image: Imgur]

Also not a word on this in all WWDC videos...

Comment: May you please add some example project link? I just created a new project with `TableView`, added Hebrew localization and change language at simulator. After scrolling I see no animations (with or without slow animations enabled), but views are RTL aligned.

Comment: Did you try `[UIView performWithoutAnimations:^{}]` in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: Is this cell being loaded from a xib? If so, how are you doing this? You shouldn't have to pre-layout each cell, that sounds like a nasty workaround.

Comment: This reproduce in UICollectionViews when scrolling horizontally. see this: https://github.com/ybeapps/BugInUICollectionViewForIOS. You can open bug at https://bugreport.apple.com They solve the bugs that has been opened many times by many developers. I've already opened a bug

Answer (score 2):

you can just animate the constraint in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, there is an example that i used in my code, but doesn't animate the constraint but instead animate the cell's contentview's layer's transform

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIView *contentView = cell.contentView;
    contentView.layer.opacity = 0.0;
    contentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.2, 2, 0.3);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     contentView.layer.opacity = 1;
                     contentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                 }];
```

}

Comment: it's the same working, just animate the constraint in the animation block

Answer (score 1):

OK, so basically `UIView`  is initiated with the original layout as it appears on the `*.XIB` file, and then change the layout as the device's localization.

The first time my `UITableViewCell`s were displayed, there were no animation and it displayed properly, I assumed my `UITableView` was reusing it cells because that's how I've defined it, but actually, due to another issue I've mistakenly caused, my tableView's content size was changed during the scroll and the old cells were not being reused, what caused to something like 20 "live" cells to be subviewed by the table view at the same time, so each new row just initiated a new `UITableViewCell`, and because at the same time there was a method executing

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
    ...

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    ...
}];
```

The cell's layout was also animating from LTR to RTL layout.

Anyway, fixing my implementation for this behaviour solved the reusing of the cells and also the weird animation caused by the global view's layout animation.

Hope it will help some else who encountered something similar.